# How to get an integer value that is greater than the maximum integer value

Tags: java, memory, int

I know that in Java an int can get a value of 2,147,483,647. But I want more value than that. I have a formula for example:

```
double x = a/(b*c);
```

So the denominator (b*c) can reach to 10^10 or maybe even higher than that. But whenever I execute the formula, the value is always limited to 2,147,483,647. I know because x must always be smaller than 1.0.
P/S: Even variable "a" can also reach 10^10 if some conditions are satisfied.
a,b,c are all integer numbers.

Comment: Are you using an int or a double? When you execute the formula, and all variables are doubles, you shouldn't hit this limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you asked for it, here's a `BigInteger` example:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("yourNumberInStringFormA");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("yourNumberInStringFormB");
BigInteger c = new BigInteger("yourNumberInStringFormC");

BigInteger x = a.divide(b.multiply(c));
```

Where `"yourNumberInStringForm"` is an optional minus sign and numbers only (no whitespace or commas).  For example `BigInteger z = new BigIntger("-3463634");`  NB: `BigInteger` will actually return a `long` for you if your number is in its range.  `longs` end in `L`, as in:

```
long num = 372036854775807L;
```

The max length for a `long` is: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  If your numbers are going to be less than that, it'll make your life a ton easier to use `long` or `Long`, its wrapper, over `BigInteger`.  Since with `long`, you don't have to use methods for dividing/multiplying, etc.

Comment: oh so basically, BigInteger value also limited by long range. So I'd better use long type because my value can only reach 9 x 10^10

Comment: No, I made an edit.  `BigInteger` will return a `long` for you when your number is smaller than a `long`.  Dealing with `longs` is much easier than `BigInteger`.  Given that your numbers are less than the max `long`, you should use `long` over `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 4):

The max int value is a java language constant. If you want real numbers larger than what `int` provides, use [long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE). If you need integers larger than what `int` and `long` provide, you can use `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("9");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("3");
BigInteger c = a.add(b); // c.equals(new BigInteger("12"), a and b are unchanged
```

`BigInteger` is immutable just like `Long` and `Integer`, but you can't use the usual operator symbols. Instead use the [methods provided](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) by the class.

I also notice you're ending up with a `double`. If it's okay to use doubles throughout your formula, it's worth noting that their max value is: `1.7976931348623157 E 308`

[Read more about java language constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html).

Comment: I do a research and I see that there are some type called BigInteger . How can I use that ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a **long** type, still an integer type but its maximum value is higher than **int**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double x = a / ((double) b * c);
```

a and c will be cast to double by java automatically. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2 *If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.*