# Solution to go past the max value of integer?

Tags: java, math

Hello dear community,

I`ve been thinking about this for quite some time now but can't seem to find a solution.

I have my `int[][] bino = new int[15][]` in which I calculate the first 15 lines of pascals pyramid and I'm not allowed to change the type (no double, long, etc).

We know that the faculty of 12 is 479001600

The max value of int is 2147483647 so fac(12) still fits in there.

Now, for the last 3 lines is where it gets complicated.

Fac(13) is 6227020800 which is too big for int.

So what happens is that for line 13,14 and 15 it won't display the right numbers
(because 6227020800 mod 2147483647 = 1932053506 which means that fac(13) = 1932053506 in my example).

The question is if there is a way to somehow still display the right numbers, without changing the type of field in `int[][] bino = new int[15][]`). Anything else can be changed.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    int[][] bino = new int[15][]; //Create 2d array for pascal pyramid
    for(int i = 0; i < bino.length;i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < bino[i].length;j++)
        {
           binos[i][j] = nOverk(i,j)
        }

}

public int nOverk(int n, int k)
{
   return(fac(n) / (fac(k) * fac((n-k))));
}
public int fac(int z) //Calculats the faculty of a number
{
   int res = 1;

   if(z == 0 || z == 1)
      return 1;

   for(int i = 2; i <= z; i++)
      res *= i;
   return res;
}
```

Comment: in `long` its possible to store bigger values than in int, or [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) I found its recommended to go `long` datatype, if possible, if not, then biginteger- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17416986/4892907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to use `long`, however you can use `int` for larger numbers (and save work) by instead calculating `fac(a)/fac(b)` which is more efficient.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] bino = new int[15][]; //Create 2d array for pascal pyramid
    for (int i = 0; i < bino.length; i++) {
        bino[i] = new int[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            bino[i][j] = nOverk(i, j);
        }
    }
}

static int nOverk(int n, int k) {
    int min = Math.min(k, n - k);
    int max = Math.max(k, n - k);
    return fac(n, max) / fac(min, 1);
}

static int fac(int hi, int lo) {
    if (hi == 0 || hi == 1)
        return 1;

    int res = 1;
    for (int i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++)
        res *= i;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAICT you only use resp. need `fac()` for `nOverk()`. In the term `fac(n) / (fac(k) * fac((n-k))))` you can cancel out some of the factors, keeping the temporary values in the allowed range.

For example, instead of `nOverk(4,2) = 4*3*2*1 / ((2*1) * (2 * 1))`, you just calculate `(4 * 3) / (2 * 1)`. There may be corner cases where that doesn't help, but I think the task is defined this way so that it helps.

```
public int nOverk(int n, int k)
{
    return (lim_fac(n, k) / lim_fac(k, k));
}

private int lim_fac(int z, int n) //Calculats the "limited" faculty of a number, by multiplying n factors.
{
   int res = 1;

   if (n == 0) {
      return 1;
   }

   if (n == 1) {
      return z;
   }

   for (int i = z - n + 1; i <= z; i++) {
      res *= i;
   }

   return res;
}
```

Note: I am not 100% sure if I got `lim_fac()` right, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

In Pascal's triangle, each number is the sum of the two numbers directly above it. If the task is just to print the first 15 rows you dont realy need to use factorial.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int n = 15;
    int[][] pascal  = new int[n+1][];

    // initialize first row
    pascal[1] = new int[1+2];
    pascal[1][1] = 1;

    // fill in Pascal's triangle
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        pascal[i] = new int[i+2];
        for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++)
            pascal[i][j] = pascal[i-1][j-1] + pascal[i-1][j];
    }

    // print results
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < pascal[i].length - 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(pascal[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably by far the best answer and should be the accepted one.